# Angular 2 - scroll to bottom of a scroll (div overflow)

Tags: angular

I have the following template code:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px">
Some content..

</div>
```

If you ever been chatting on Facebook Messenger, you might have noticed the messages are scrolling automically to the bottom of the div, so the users can see the latest message.

I'm trying to achieve the same - I'm using angular to insert content to an array, and show a list of items. sometimes this list's height is getting too big.

How I can make the div scrolling to the bottom of the overflow-y with angular 2?

Comment: So you want to fire "scroll" on every array insert action?

Comment: One trick I used in angular 1 was to check for the last element in the ng-repeat and if it was then fire off a scroll to the bottom... I think that there is a similar "last" property on the ngFor in angular 2

Comment: @AngJobs yep and in page load

Comment: What do I exactly have to fire? What's the code for the bottom scrolling?

Comment: Did you get a good answer for this? Perhaps some code you can share?